# Anti-vspace* command?

Tags: spacing, vspace

`\vspace{}` will add space only if the subsequent text is not the first thing on the page. `\vspace*{}` will add space in either case. Is there a command that will *only* add space if the subsequent text is the first thing on the page?

My use case here is that I would like more space (automatically) above my sections if they start on a new page.

Comment: Weird idea but maybe `\vspace{-1cm}\vspace*{1cm}`?

Comment: I'm a weird guy... yeah that works.. should have thought of that myself! Thanks